# Databricks Spark SQL query plan optimization to avoid read duplicate

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

I have a spark SQL query as below:

```
with xxx as (
select pb_id, pb_name, req_id, level, t_val_id_path
from(
  select pb_id, pb_name, req_id, explode(req_vals) as t_id
  from A
  where dt = '2022-11-20') a
join (
  select t_val_id, level, t_val_id_path
  from B
  where dt = '2022-11-20')b
on a.t_id = b.t_val_id)
select distinct 
  pb_id, req_id, -1 as l1, -1 as l2, -1 as l3
from xxx 
union all
select distinct 
  pb_id, req_id, t_val_id_path[0] as l1, -1 as l2, -1 as l3
from xxx 
union all
select distinct 
  pb_id, req_id, t_val_id_path[0] as l1, t_val_id_path[1] as l2, -1 as l3
from xxx 
where level > 0
union all
select distinct
  pb_id, req_id, t_val_id_path[0] as l1, if(level > 0, t_val_id_path[1], 1) as l2, if(level > 1, t_val_id_path[2], 1) as l3
from xxx;
```

In Azure Databricks, the SQL query plan is below:
[image]

**Question**:
From the SQL script it may just read table A & B of hive table. But in the query plan, we could see that we would read A **4 times** and B **4 times**. Is it possible that we read A & B just once and then do the filter and transformation in memory instead to read it again and again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try to cache your xxx table. You can use cache also in sql, not only in df api

https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview/sql-ref-syntax-aux-cache-cache-table.html

So imo it may look like this:

```
spark.sql("CACHE TABLE xxx as (
select pb_id, pb_name, req_id, level, t_val_id_path
from(
  select pb_id, pb_name, req_id, explode(req_vals) as t_id
  from A
  where dt = '2022-11-20') a
join (
  select t_val_id, level, t_val_id_path
  from B
  where dt = '2022-11-20')b
on a.t_id = b.t_val_id)")

spark.sql(
    "select distinct 
      pb_id, req_id, -1 as l1, -1 as l2, -1 as l3
    from xxx 
    union all
    select distinct 
      pb_id, req_id, t_val_id_path[0] as l1, -1 as l2, -1 as l3
    from xxx 
    union all
    select distinct 
      pb_id, req_id, t_val_id_path[0] as l1, t_val_id_path[1] as l2, -1 as l3
    from xxx 
    where level > 0
    union all
    select distinct
      pb_id, req_id, t_val_id_path[0] as l1, if(level > 0, t_val_id_path[1], 1) as l2, if(level > 1, t_val_id_path[2], 1) as l3
    from xxx"
)
```

Comment: Got the following error message
AnalysisException: Temporary view 'xxx' already exists

Comment: It seems that the uncache command may not delete the table and thus it will still exists.
Could you also help explain a bit more about the difference for sql command "cache table xxx as" and a=spark.sql("select *); a.createOrReplaceTempView("xxx"); spark.catalog.cacheTable("xxx")? And how to remove the cache?
From my understanding when the notebook job complete and next run the temp view should be not available, but the cache table is still there and it is out of my knowledge.

Comment: "the difference for sql command "cache table xxx as" and a=spark.sql("select *); a.createOrReplaceTempView("xxx"); spark.catalog.cacheTable("xxx")" I think that there is not difference, at the end result will be the same, you are going to have table called xxx loaded to cache. "And how to remove the cache?" - to remove from cache you can use uncache (in sql) or unpersist on df. Keep in mind that this is going to eject df from cache, but view will still be there so thats may be the reason why you are getting error that view already exists.

Comment: "From my understanding when the notebook job complete and next run the temp view should be not available, but the cache table is still there and it is out of my knowledge." - you mean that it exists between cells in your notebook? If you create a view in cell one and cache it cell2 its normal behaviour that they are going to be avilable in cell3 and above if cluster was not restarted. You need to manualy eject it from cache and drop the view. Remember that you can always check what is in your cache on SparkUI in storage tab